# Multiprocessing using pools for a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, multiprocessing

Could someone please explain to me how I rewrite this code to run faster using pools? Sorry for that question but I'm a beginner and I spent so much time trying but unfortunately I couldn't figure it out.

```
for i in constituents:
    print(i) # print out the ticker so we know the downloading progress
    prc = yf.download(i, interval="1d", start=start_date, end=end_date)
    prc = pd.DataFrame(prc['Adj Close']) # select adjusted close price only
    prc.columns = [i] # rename the column with the ticker of the stock
    try:
        df_prc = pd.concat([df_prc, prc], axis=1) # if the dataframe already exists, join the newly downloaded data to the existing table
    except:
        df_prc = prc # create the dataframe for the first ticker
        
    stk = yf.Ticker(i)
    
    try:
        stk.info['floatShares']
    except:
        stk.info['floatShares'] = None
    try:
        stk.info['sharesOutstanding']
    except:
        stk.info['sharesOutstanding'] = None
    if stk.info['floatShares']:
        mcap = prc * stk.info['floatShares']
    elif stk.info['sharesOutstanding']:
        mcap = prc * stk.info['sharesOutstanding']
    else:
        mcap = prc * ((stk.info['marketCap'])/(stk.info['previousClose']))
    try:
        df_mcap = pd.concat([df_mcap, mcap], axis=1)
    except:
        df_mcap = mcap
```

Further, I would like to provide the code that runs befor that one I posted to clarify my question:

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

start_date = "2021-01-04"
end_date = "2021-11-29"
idx = "^STOXX50E"


Index = yf.download(idx, # ticker
                    interval="1d", # daily frequency
                    start=start_date, end=end_date) # sampling period

Index = pd.DataFrame(Index['Adj Close'].rename(idx)) # select adjusted close price

page = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EURO_STOXX_50')

constituents = page[2]['Ticker'] # we only need tickers

constituents.pop(46) # Ticker UMG.AS is removed because otherwise the for loop produces an error
```

Comment: What is `yf`?  What is `stk`? What is `constituents` (for example, how many elements are in it)?  Is there a limit on the download rate you are allowed when you do `yf.download`? Perhaps a combination of multithreading and multiprocessing is the optimal solution. It would help if you could post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This cannot be answered as currently asked.

Comment: Hi Booboo, thank for your answer! 

Sorry, I see your point that I have not given enough information. 

yf: it stands for yfinance which I imported as followed "import yfinance as yf"
constituents: this is a pandas series that consists of 49 Stock Tickers.
stk: this gives back the yfinance ticker for every object/ticker that the loop runs over

Comment: I have also added the code needed to reproduce my problem. 

Excuse me again for articulating my question like that. I would really like to figure out how it works but as I am new to Python no approach of mine worked. 

To be transparent, this is for an project at my university. However, this is only bonus, so that our code runs faster, and the Professor said that he does not expect us to find a soultion. Nevertheless, out of interest I asked here in the forum because I was reading here some interesting threads on multiprocessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reduce the running time from 386 seconds to 17 seconds with the following code. Note that I had to do an import of module `ssl` and issue `ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context` to overcome an SSL certificate error I was getting from the `pd.read_html()` method call.

```py
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from functools import partial
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

start_date = "2021-01-04"
end_date = "2021-11-29"

def process_constituent(data, constituent):
    prc = pd.DataFrame(data[constituent]['Adj Close']) # select adjusted close price only
    prc.columns = [constituent] # rename the column with the ticker of the stock

    stk = yf.Ticker(constituent)

    try:
        stk.info['floatShares']
    except:
        stk.info['floatShares'] = None
    try:
        stk.info['sharesOutstanding']
    except:
        stk.info['sharesOutstanding'] = None
    if stk.info['floatShares']:
        mcap = prc * stk.info['floatShares']
    elif stk.info['sharesOutstanding']:
        mcap = prc * stk.info['sharesOutstanding']
    else:
        mcap = prc * ((stk.info['marketCap'])/(stk.info['previousClose']))
    return mcap

def process_constituents(constituents):
    # Download all the tickers:
    data = yf.download(
            tickers = ' '.join(constituents),
            interval='1d',
            start = start_date,
            end = end_date,
            group_by = 'ticker',
            adjust=False,
            threads = True,
            proxy = None
            )
    pool = ThreadPool(len(constituents))
    for idx, mcap in enumerate(pool.imap(partial(process_constituent, data), constituents)):
        if idx == 0:
            df_mcap = mcap
        else:
            df_mcap = pd.concat([df_mcap, mcap], axis=1)
    return df_mcap


def main():
    idx = "^STOXX50E"

    Index = yf.download(idx, # ticker
                        interval="1d", # daily frequency
                        start=start_date, end=end_date) # sampling period

    Index = pd.DataFrame(Index['Adj Close'].rename(idx)) # select adjusted close price

    page = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EURO_STOXX_50')
    constituents = page[2]['Ticker'] # we only need tickers
    constituents.pop(46) # Ticker UMG.AS is removed because otherwise the for loop produces an error
    df_mcap = process_constituents(constituents)
    print(df_mcap)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 completed
[*********************100%***********************]  49 of 49 completed
                  ADS.DE      ADYEN.AS         AD.AS         AI.PA  ...        TTE.PA         DG.PA        VOW.DE        VNA.DE
Date                                                                ...
2021-01-04  5.083322e+10  4.880933e+10  2.414267e+10  6.200227e+10  ...  8.326552e+10  3.746300e+10  3.842743e+10  3.322534e+10
2021-01-05  4.983515e+10  4.800875e+10  2.403104e+10  6.134340e+10  ...  8.545638e+10  3.682896e+10  3.849667e+10  3.338207e+10
2021-01-06  5.019652e+10  4.548888e+10  2.411223e+10  6.147971e+10  ...  8.921219e+10  3.824197e+10  3.886594e+10  3.203872e+10
2021-01-07  4.964585e+10  4.500328e+10  2.407163e+10  6.195684e+10  ...  9.018724e+10  3.830537e+10  3.946601e+10  3.183722e+10
2021-01-08  5.078160e+10  4.610573e+10  2.400059e+10  6.232034e+10  ...  9.024743e+10  3.879449e+10  3.893518e+10  3.225142e+10
...                  ...           ...           ...           ...  ...           ...           ...           ...           ...
2021-11-22  4.851034e+10  6.454539e+10  3.178177e+10  7.108912e+10  ...  1.073903e+11  4.175263e+10  6.518791e+10  2.937961e+10
2021-11-23  4.727562e+10  6.298360e+10  3.187473e+10  7.017166e+10  ...  1.086315e+11  4.224230e+10  6.532881e+10  2.843048e+10
2021-11-24  4.667566e+10  6.206490e+10  3.153388e+10  7.028287e+10  ...  1.092141e+11  4.271798e+10  6.326233e+10  2.985586e+10
2021-11-25  4.659740e+10  6.453227e+10  3.159068e+10  7.013459e+10  ...  1.091381e+11  4.279726e+10  6.298054e+10  3.005144e+10
2021-11-26  4.405841e+10  6.358732e+10  3.132214e+10  6.882791e+10  ...  1.026661e+11  3.918302e+10  6.072620e+10  2.859604e+10

[233 rows x 49 columns]
```

Comment: Dear Booboo, 
First, I want to thank you very much! 
I am impressed that you achieved to bring it down to 17 seconds because my professor said that he it would be good if we achieve to cute the time by half. I am currently studying the code and I am trying to understand it. 
Again, thank you very much for taking the time and effort!

Comment: The big gains is the modified call to `yf.download()` which uses yfinance's own built-in multithreading support to download all 49 tickers concurrently. Then I use multithreading  to do the remaining processing on each of these 49 returned results in `process_constituent`.

Comment: You are right, the modified call to yf.download() makes a big difference. I made only a few changes to your code because with your code I only get the df_mcap but I also need df_prc. I now realized that still after editing my question I should have given more information like what results I want to get. Below I'll post my current code.

Comment: I know my code looks not that good like yours, but like I said I just started to programm, and the course this is for is also not a programming but an finance course. But you helped me very much, and I will try to enhance another code in the same way.

Comment: I changed:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

to:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    df_mcap = process_constituents(constituents)

I did this because a NameError (name 'df_mcap' is not defined) later when the following code referred to it would occur.  Do you know why this is the case?

Comment: The "following code" doesn't seem to generate a `NameError` so I don't know what it looked like when it did. And as far as `process_dfproc` is concerned, it creates a thread pool and uses it to call `process_prc` for each ticker. But this function just returns a column and there is no I/O or network waiting involved. So unless `pandas` releases the Global Interpreter Lock during its processing for this, you will not gain any degree of concurrency by using threading and even then it may not be a significant performance improvement.

Comment: It's important to understand the limitations of multithreading and what the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) is and what role it plays in multithreading performance.

Comment: You are right, I definitely need more understand how multithreading work. But again, thank you very much for your help, I was very impressed by the result, and how much your code was able to reduce the computing time.

Answer (score 0):

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from functools import partial
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

start_date = "2021-01-04"
end_date = "2021-11-29"

# download data

idx = "^STOXX50E"

Index = yf.download(idx, # ticker
                        interval="1d", # daily frequency
                        start=start_date, end=end_date) # sampling period

Index = pd.DataFrame(Index['Adj Close'].rename(idx)) # select adjusted close price

page = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EURO_STOXX_50')
constituents = page[2]['Ticker'] # we only need tickers
constituents.pop(46) # Ticker UMG.AS is removed because otherwise the for loop produces an error

data = yf.download(
            tickers = ' '.join(constituents),
            interval='1d',
            start = start_date,
            end = end_date,
            group_by = 'ticker',
            adjust=False,
            threads = True,
            proxy = None
            )

def process_prc(data, constituent):
    prc = pd.DataFrame(data[constituent]['Adj Close']) # select adjusted close price only
    prc.columns = [constituent] # rename the column with the ticker of the stock
       
    return prc

def process_constituent(data, constituent):
    prc = pd.DataFrame(data[constituent]['Adj Close']) # select adjusted close price only
    prc.columns = [constituent] # rename the column with the ticker of the stock

    stk = yf.Ticker(constituent)

    try:
        stk.info['floatShares']
    except:
        stk.info['floatShares'] = None
    try:
        stk.info['sharesOutstanding']
    except:
        stk.info['sharesOutstanding'] = None
    if stk.info['floatShares']:
        mcap = prc * stk.info['floatShares']
    elif stk.info['sharesOutstanding']:
        mcap = prc * stk.info['sharesOutstanding']
    else:
        mcap = prc * ((stk.info['marketCap'])/(stk.info['previousClose']))
    return mcap



def process_dfprc(constituents):
    pool = ThreadPool(len(constituents))
    for idx, prc in enumerate(pool.imap(partial(process_prc, data), constituents)):
        try:
            df_prc = pd.concat([df_prc, prc], axis=1) # if the dataframe already exists, join the newly downloaded data to the existing table
        except:
            df_prc = prc # create the dataframe for the first ticker

    return df_prc 

def process_constituents(constituents):
    # Download all the tickers:
    pool = ThreadPool(len(constituents))
    for idx, mcap in enumerate(pool.imap(partial(process_constituent, data), constituents)):
        #if idx == 0:
           # df_mcap = mcap
        #else:
           # df_mcap = pd.concat([df_mcap, mcap], axis=1)
        try:
            df_mcap = pd.concat([df_mcap, mcap], axis=1)
        except:
            df_mcap = mcap
    return df_mcap
    

    page = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EURO_STOXX_50')
    constituents = page[2]['Ticker'] # we only need tickers
    constituents.pop(46) # Ticker UMG.AS is removed because otherwise the for loop produces an error
```

calculating df_mcap:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    df_mcap = process_constituents(constituents)

df_mcap
```

print:

```
        ADS.DE  ADYEN.AS    AD.AS   AI.PA   AIR.PA  ALV.DE  ABI.BR  ASML.AS CS.PA   BAS.DE  ... SAF.PA  SAN.PA  SAP.DE  SU.PA   SIE.DE  STLA.MI TTE.PA  DG.PA   VOW.DE  VNA.DE
Date                                                                                    
2021-01-04  5.083322e+10    4.880933e+10    2.414267e+10    6.200227e+10    6.001130e+10    7.936595e+10    5.306992e+10    1.647683e+11    3.507867e+10    5.679746e+10    ... 4.005571e+10    8.460465e+10    1.080643e+11    6.363292e+10    9.197665e+10    2.174885e+10    8.763420e+10    3.746300e+10    3.842743e+10    3.316382e+10
2021-01-05  4.983515e+10    4.800875e+10    2.403104e+10    6.134340e+10    5.997124e+10    7.855080e+10    5.304209e+10    1.650319e+11    3.506423e+10    5.636858e+10    ... 4.014193e+10    8.459394e+10    1.077770e+11    6.303187e+10    9.178897e+10    2.169038e+10    8.994003e+10    3.682896e+10    3.849667e+10    3.332026e+10
2021-01-06  5.019652e+10    4.548888e+10    2.411223e+10    6.147971e+10    6.019823e+10    8.263458e+10    5.451703e+10    1.633893e+11    3.656208e+10    5.896818e+10    ... 4.010744e+10    8.407989e+10    1.082285e+11    6.478275e+10    9.530789e+10    2.123436e+10    9.389289e+10    3.824197e+10    3.886594e+10    3.197940e+10
2021-01-07  4.964585e+10    4.500328e+10    2.407163e+10    6.195684e+10    5.983105e+10    8.195529e+10    5.417381e+10    1.638151e+11    3.678766e+10    5.987848e+10    ... 3.993501e+10    8.323385e+10    1.072435e+11    6.611552e+10    9.720029e+10    2.161438e+10    9.491911e+10    3.830537e+10    3.946601e+10    3.177828e+10
2021-01-08  5.078160e+10    4.610573e+10    2.400059e+10    6.232034e+10    6.015150e+10    8.221501e+10    5.367288e+10    1.687430e+11    3.675157e+10    6.002728e+10    ... 4.012468e+10    8.437975e+10    1.089467e+11    6.682110e+10    9.696569e+10    2.121390e+10    9.498246e+10    3.879449e+10    3.893518e+10    3.219170e+10
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2021-11-22  4.851034e+10    6.454539e+10    3.178177e+10    7.108912e+10    7.262242e+10    8.481195e+10    4.905974e+10    3.047505e+11    4.871214e+10    5.686775e+10    ... 3.862038e+10    9.936060e+10    1.269160e+11    8.638617e+10    1.251472e+11    3.187450e+10    1.074238e+11    4.175263e+10    6.518791e+10    2.937961e+10
2021-11-23  4.727562e+10    6.298360e+10    3.187473e+10    7.017166e+10    7.361048e+10    8.489549e+10    4.868553e+10    2.879491e+11    4.890396e+10    5.780438e+10    ... 3.883494e+10    9.827092e+10    1.247044e+11    8.521374e+10    1.230764e+11    3.105655e+10    1.086654e+11    4.224230e+10    6.532881e+10    2.843048e+10
2021-11-24  4.667566e+10    6.206490e+10    3.153388e+10    7.028287e+10    7.441161e+10    8.483284e+10    4.900361e+10    2.891317e+11    4.899028e+10    5.683102e+10    ... 3.892492e+10    9.708117e+10    1.240785e+11    8.322063e+10    1.219527e+11    3.068774e+10    1.092482e+11    4.271798e+10    6.326233e+10    2.985586e+10
2021-11-25  4.659740e+10    6.453227e+10    3.159068e+10    7.013459e+10    7.494570e+10    8.464487e+10    5.084663e+10    2.899473e+11    4.885600e+10    5.657391e+10    ... 3.898721e+10    9.634731e+10    1.249965e+11    8.351906e+10    1.232691e+11    3.050516e+10    1.091722e+11    4.279726e+10    6.298054e+10    3.005144e+10
2021-11-26  4.405841e+10    6.358732e+10    3.132214e+10    6.882791e+10    6.633355e+10    7.996257e+10    4.789032e+10    2.795891e+11    4.646787e+10    5.317635e+10    ... 3.498675e+10    9.452378e+10    1.201978e+11    8.077986e+10    1.165751e+11    2.842012e+10    1.026981e+11    3.918302e+10    6.072620e+10    2.859604e+10
233 rows × 49 columns
```

calculating df_prc:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    df_prc = process_dfprc(constituents)

df_prc
```

print:

```
    ADS.DE  ADYEN.AS    AD.AS   AI.PA   AIR.PA  ALV.DE  ABI.BR  ASML.AS CS.PA   BAS.DE  ... SAF.PA  SAN.PA  SAP.DE  SU.PA   SIE.DE  STLA.MI TTE.PA  DG.PA   VOW.DE  VNA.DE
Date                                                                                    
2021-01-04  292.307343  1859.5  23.374092   133.809341  89.889999   190.011627  56.726482   404.039764  18.287489   61.853455   ... 115.747612  76.089233   103.588997  119.404495  114.593018  11.912073   34.584999   80.331764   163.641632  57.650417
2021-01-05  286.568085  1829.0  23.266014   132.387405  89.830002   188.060059  56.696735   404.686218  18.279963   61.386387   ... 115.996742  76.079597   103.313599  118.276649  114.359184  11.880051   35.494999   78.972191   163.936478  57.922352
2021-01-06  288.646088  1733.0  23.344616   132.681595  90.169998   197.837112  58.273296   400.658264  19.060837   64.217407   ... 115.897095  75.617287   103.746368  121.562111  118.743378  11.630281   37.055000   82.002113   165.509003  55.591476
2021-01-07  285.479584  1714.5  23.305313   133.711288  89.620003   196.210800  57.906425   401.702545  19.178438   65.208740   ... 115.398827  74.856400   102.802139  124.062988  121.101105  11.838422   37.459999   82.138069   168.064377  55.241844
2021-01-08  292.010498  1756.5  23.236538   134.495789  90.099998   196.832611  57.370987   413.786438  19.159622   65.370781   ... 115.946915  75.886971   104.434860  125.386978  120.808823  11.619075   37.485001   83.186890   165.803864  55.960529
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2021-11-22  278.950012  2459.0  30.770000   153.419998  108.779999  203.050003  52.439999   747.299988  25.395000   61.930000   ... 111.599998  89.360001   121.660004  162.100006  155.919998  17.458000   42.395000   89.529999   277.600006  51.072109
2021-11-23  271.850006  2399.5  30.860001   151.440002  110.260002  203.250000  52.040001   706.099976  25.495001   62.950001   ... 112.220001  88.379997   119.540001  159.899994  153.339996  17.010000   42.884998   90.580002   278.200012  49.422203
2021-11-24  268.399994  2364.5  30.530001   151.679993  111.459999  203.100006  52.380001   709.000000  25.540001   61.889999   ... 112.480003  87.309998   118.940002  156.160004  151.940002  16.808001   43.115002   91.599998   269.399994  51.900002
2021-11-25  267.950012  2458.5  30.584999   151.360001  112.260002  202.649994  54.349998   711.000000  25.469999   61.610001   ... 112.660004  86.650002   119.820000  156.720001  153.580002  16.708000   43.084999   91.769997   268.200012  52.240002
2021-11-26  253.350006  2422.5  30.325001   148.539993  99.360001   191.440002  51.189999   685.599976  24.225000   57.910000   ... 101.099998  85.010002   115.220001  151.580002  145.240005  15.566000   40.529999   84.019997   258.600006  49.709999
233 rows × 49 columns
```